# Comparing two items if matches powershell

Tags: powershell

I am exporting drive name movies in text file.

```
Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk| foreach-object {$volumename -Match "movies" } | select movies > c:\nn.txt
```

And later comparing it but not successful always getting false result can anyone help?

```
$test=Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk| foreach-object {$volumename -Match "movies" } | select movies > c:\nn.txt
    $array =get-content c:\nn.txt
    $real= Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk| foreach-object {$volumename -Match "movies"} | select movies
    If ($array -eq $real)

    {write-host "it was success" -foregroundcolor blue}
    Else {write-host "it was fail" -foregroundcolor green}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk | ? Volumename -eq "movies" | select -ExpandProperty Volumename | out-file "c:\nn.txt"
$array =get-content  "c:\nn.txt"
$real =  get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk | ? Volumename -eq "movies" | select -ExpandProperty Volumename
If ($array -eq $real)

{write-host "it was success" -foregroundcolor blue}
Else {write-host "it was fail" -foregroundcolor green}
```

Comment: This command 

 get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk | ? Volumename -eq "movies" | select -ExpandProperty Volumename not suppoted in powershell 2.0

Comment: use get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk | ? {$_.Volumename -eq "movies"} | select -ExpandProperty Volumename